# Is it not redundant for the magnetic field to induce voltage if its partner electric field hits at the receiving antenna?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, antennas

If the electric  field hits the receiving antenna (in form of pressure or voltage) to agitate the electrons in the receiving antenna, then what is the purpose of magnetic field then? What it serves for?

Comment: What if your receiving antenna is a loop (see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_antenna)?  As varying magnetic field through the loop will induce a current in the loop, what's the purpose of the electric field then?  This section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_antenna#Magnetic_vs._electrical_antennas is also instructive.

Comment: So, do you accept the sense of redundancy for some instance? or, Do you imply the other partner field is useless for some instance?

Comment: Would you mean that in some instance, the other partner field is useless? If these partners arrive together at the antenna, we can think electric field (voltage or pressure) does its work by pushing or agitating the electrons,then what magnetic field could help with its partner? You imply its useful in a loop antenna. If so, then in some instance, magnetic field is useless. Is it right to understanding like that? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: My advice to you, depending on your age, is to study the necessary mathematics for the physics you need to understand, in university courses , there are free ones on line if you are of an older persuasion.

Comment: Actually, I have advanced mathematics background. But, my realization is,  every time we analyze certain phenomenon with the aid of mathematics , the deep understanding or the essence of its existence is very much important rather than relying only the tool and interpreting its results and stop there.  Even if we expressed our answer in mathematical equations, we still need to touch the real meaning behind that mathematical equations.

Comment: Example. What is mechanical force? and we answer,  Mechanical Force is mass times acceleration and we stop there. with that, we are not showing the essential meaning of it. We could be interpreted as master in  certain subject matter if we could able to go deeper with it.  Like questioning ourselves, what cause that mechanical force to exist? If it is a product of mass and acceleration, which of the two that brings the force? Is it the mass or the acceleration? If it is the mass, then what makes the mass to exist? and then you realize it goes down to gravity. This is what I mean.

Comment: @Pisoko +2 to your last comments.

Comment: I believe if we really have deeply understood  a certain phenomenon, we don't need to memorize its mathematical equations because we could able to derive those equations  anytime and even until the end of our life time; provided,  that  our brain is not yet deteriorated or damaged  and/or we have at least occasionally visited its corresponding field of science.

Answer (score 1):

Electromagnetic waves are  independent of the source, once generated, because varying electric fields and magnetic fields can move through the vacuum without need of reinforcement by a source ( as happens in an electric circuit). They become independent. In the classical mathematical description of light

[image: emwave]

> [Electromagnetic waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) can be imagined as a self-propagating transverse oscillating wave of electric and magnetic fields. This 3D animation shows a plane linearly polarized wave propagating from left to right. Note that the electric and magnetic fields in such a wave are in-phase with each other, reaching minima and maxima together

So the magnetic field is necessary for the existence of the self propagating wave.

Comment: You main magnetic field is necessary to preserve its existence while propagating? Is it necessary to do that for the magnetic field if that electric field is existed by electrical charges? Would you mean that electric field diminishes or decreases as it travels away and thus magnetic field is necessary to maintain its existence?

Comment: all the above falls beautifully  in place when studying maxwell's equation. Before his brilliant studies, there was no concept of electromagnetic waves. Light is a higher frequency electromagnetic wave.

Comment: It is the mathematics that helps to understand the stability of the self propelled em wave. Look at the annimation.

Comment: @annav what a nice animation!  I've seen those before of course but rarely on this site.

Comment: I already encountered that Maxwell's equation.  But, my question is at the point of arrival , these two partners hit the receiving antenna, how does the two work together? We know that electric field is a force (Newton per Coulomb, Volts per meter) , so there is a pressure or voltage at the antenna that pushes or agitates the electrons by this electric field; now, here is magnetic field, which also induces voltage, are these two overlapping their responsibilities? What is really their respective functions at this point?

Comment: I appreciate you graphical representation of electromagnetic wave.  It could give more clear to understand if you can explain like this: That up and down wave means amount or quantity of fields that varies periodically as it travels from transmitter to receiver. This wave can be visualize as light. Some is omni directional like star and some is directional like laser light. So it is true that both fields reach the antenna like laser light hit the antenna but the type of antenna limits its ability to take either one of the two fields.  Correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you for your helpful answer.

Comment: yes , the type of antenna will decide whether the magentic field part of the wave will be received and processed further ( the electrical engineering part, more mathematics).

Comment: Actually,  calculus, differential equations,  linear and non-linear equations, series and transforms, vector algebra, matrices, stochastic processes and random variables are not new to me. I already encountered these math thingy and solved problems involving with those mathematics.

Comment: However, being able to skillfully manipulate, interpret and solve scientific or engineering problems with those math are not enough so that we could flauntingly claim that we fully understood certain phenomenon expressed with those math unless we could able to elucidate profoundly the meaning behind those equations to the point that we could go down to the abyss of its existence.

Answer (score 1):

@annav 's answer illustrates very nicely that, for the wave to propagate from the emitter to the receiver,  you need both the electric and magnetic field.

To simplify matter, suppose the wave propagates in air.  Then the ratio of  the magnitudes of the electric to magnetic field is constant (and about 377 if you care to know).  The electric and magnetic field both decrease in amplitude at the same rate, which by geometry is usually $1/r^2$ with $r$ the distance from the emitter to the receiver, i.e. if a first receiver is twice as far a second receiver, the first will detect an amplitude of 1/4 compared to the second.

The propagation is such that you cannot propagate an electromagnetic wave by propagating the electric or magnetic field alone: both are required.  You need the varying $\vec E$ to produce a varying $\vec B$ which in turn produces a varying $\vec E$ in perpertual induction one to the other.

Once the wave reaches the receiving antenna, only one or the other field will usually "couple" to the receiving antenna.  The details depend on the antenna but the simplest cases are the short line antenna (or Hertzian dipole) or the small loop antenna.  In the case of the latter, it is the magnetic field that drives the antenna, while in the former it is the electric field.

Please be aware that the above two cases are just the simplest and that antenna design is quite a specialize field of electrical engineering, with some antenna design cleverly optimized for specific applications.

Thus, neither field is really redundant since

1. they are both required for propagation, and
2. which one will "activate" the antenna actually depends on the antenna, and there are probably models where both "activate" the antenna.